java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile
Using CAS Apereo 6.6.8 that is packaging pac4j v5.4.6.
I am getting a cast exception when user logs out after they use OIDC to delegate authentication against Azure AD.
in org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager class when getting the profile:
final var profile = entry.getValue();

The getValue looks to be an encrypted object.
Versus a debug statement in the saveAll method seems to output the actual profile object with user attributes in plain text.
Is this a known issue with this version? Is the object being saved to session getting encrypted but not decrypted with retrieving the UserProfile object?

Can you copy/paste the full stack trace exception?

I added stack trace in another comment to keep formatting. Also, in google community group, I see this same issue reported when mongodb and postgres ticket persistence.

I also have thread on google cas group.
See stack trace below. Line numbers may not align with source as I added debugging statements.
(ProfileManager.java:111)
is this snippet:
 final var profile = entry.getValue();

Looks like value of entry.getValue() is in this format which I think is the problem:
key=AzureAdClient
value=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

Stack trace:
2024-04-22 07:49:29,427 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-56) Forwarding to error page from request [/logout] due to exception [Exception thrown executing org.apereo.cas.web.flow.actions.DelegatedAuthenticationClientLogoutAction@56d11f00 in state 'terminateSession' of flow 'logout' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]']: org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.apereo.cas.web.flow.actions.DelegatedAuthenticationClientLogoutAction@56d11f00 in state 'terminateSession' of flow 'logout' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'                                                                                                                                                                                              
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:62)                                                                                                      
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)                                                                                                       
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)                                                                                                        
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)                                                                                                      
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:154)                                                                                                                
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:193)                                                                                                                            
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)                                                                                                                              
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)                                                                                               
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)                                                                                               
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:139)                                                                                          
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:264)                                                                                            
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)                                                                                                 
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)                                                                                                   
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)                                                                                                                   
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)                                                                                                                   
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)                                                                                            
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)                                                                                  
    at deployment.cas.war//com.newco.cas.config.LanguageFilter.doFilter(LanguageFilter.java:75)                                                                                                                        
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  
    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)                                                                            
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  
    at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:28)                            
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  
    at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.web.support.filters.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:401)                                                     
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  
    at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.web.support.filters.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:209)                                                                   
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)        
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.web.support.filters.AddResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(AddResponseHeadersFilter.java:62)                                                                                    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  
        at deployment.cas.war//com.newco.cas.config.LanguageFilter.doFilter(LanguageFilter.java:75)                                                                                                                        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)                                                                                             at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)                                                                                                     at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)                                                                                       at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)                                                                                             at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)                                                                                       at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)                                                                                               at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)                                                                                              at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)                                                                                               at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)                                                                                  at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)                                                                    at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)                                                                                               at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)                                                                                                       at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:104)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:66)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)                                              
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:64)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
        at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.cas.war' @6d8747fc)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager.removeOrRenewExpiredProfiles(ProfileManager.java:111)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager.retrieveAll(ProfileManager.java:99)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager.getProfile(ProfileManager.java:54)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.web.flow.actions.DelegatedAuthenticationClientLogoutAction.findCurrentProfile(DelegatedAuthenticationClientLogoutAction.java:101)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.apereo.cas.web.flow.actions.DelegatedAuthenticationClientLogoutAction.doPreExecute(DelegatedAuthenticationClientLogoutAction.java:48)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:186)
        at deployment.cas.war//org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
         ... 125 more


It's a base64 encoding of the serialized profile. I'm not sure why we get there. Do you have the same problem when upgrading to CAS v6.6.15? In any case, CAS v6.6.x does no longer receive any bugfix: https://apereo.github.io/cas/developer/Maintenance-Policy.html#eol-schedule

Yes, same error with v6.6.15:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.pac4j.core.profile.UserProfile is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.cas.war' @4319c17d)                                                                                                                                              at deployment.cas.war//org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager.removeOrRenewExpiredProfiles(ProfileManager.java:98)

Currently testing a patch committed to cas repo that is overlaying DelegatedClientJacksonModule.java. With minor mods I have it working to properly decode AzureAdProfile object.

Great! Do you see the same issue with CAS v7.0/7.1?

I haven't had a chance to test it yet as requires JDK21 and updated wildfly. I will test by next week and let you know.
